# Path to sdk not working when trying to run calabash backdoors

Tags: android, ubuntu, path, environment-variables, calabash

I am trying to run `calabash-android console` to run some backdoors on a project I'm working on but every time I try to run it I get this error:

```
$ calabash-android console app//build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
Starting calabash-android console...
Loading /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.9.0/irbrc
Running irb...
 WARN: Did not find 'adb' in any standard directory of '/media/jack/OS/Users/jackb/AppData/Local/Android/sdk'. Calabash will therefore take longer to load
 WARN: Did not find 'aapt' in any standard directory of '/media/jack/OS/Users/jackb/AppData/Local/Android/sdk'. Calabash will therefore take longer to load
 WARN: Did not find 'zipalign' in any standard directory of '/media/jack/OS/Users/jackb/AppData/Local/Android/sdk'. Calabash will therefore take longer to load
ERROR: Could not locate Android dependency
ERROR: You can read about how Calabash is searching for an Android SDK and how you can help here:
ERROR: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/documentation/installation.md#prerequisites
```

However I have created environment variables for ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME which I copied the path from the folder the sdk is contained in.

I wouldn't be asking but i feel I've tried everything.

I also should add i definitely have them installed I just don't understand why my path is not finding them (I've also tried making the path go more and less into directories).